# 5456.367 -> 5456.367188. Is this because float precision in c?

Tags: c, precision

I have a program in C like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float number = 0;
    scanf("%f", &number);
    printf("%f\n", number);
}
```

And the output is:

```sh
ururay@note:~/workspace/c/float-precision$ gcc float-precision.c -o float-precision
ururay@note:~/workspace/c/float-precision$ ./float-precision 
5456.367
5456.367188
```

I have executed this program several times and the output is the same. Is the '188' "appended" to the end of the number because float precision? If so, how could I identify this in binary representation?

Comment: Short answer : Yes. Long answer : Yes.

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) Also note that nothing was "appended" nor is the `5456.367` "present" in the `float`'s *binary* value. The default number of places by `printf` is 6, so you can do: `printf("%.3f\n", number);` to get 3 places. But here, you have 7 significant digits, around the limit of what can be done with `float` type anyway.

Comment: Your question as asked is answered "yes", anything else you meant to ask is almost guaranteed to be a duplicate of Weathers proposals. Please [edit] to ask something else or confirm the duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `5456.367` cannot be represented exactly in the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) single-precision floating point format.

The closest number is `5456.3671875`, which has the binary representation `01000101101010101000001011110000`. The next smaller representable number is `5456.3666992`, which has the binary representation `01000101101010101000001011101111`.

Comment: Indeed, it can't be exactly represented in any binary floating point format, no matter how many bits of precision you have.  `367/1000` is in lowest terms, and its denominator is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you want a better precision try using `double` or `long double` (but `long double` is way slower than other type or refer to the same type as `double`).

Also printf only takes `double` and `long double` go look at [the spec of printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: In fact, putting double makes 5456.367 -> 5456.367000.

Comment: @ThiagoUruray: Even a `double` cannot represent the number exactly. It is represented as `5456.367000000000189174897968769073486328125`. You must print more digits in order to see the inaccuracy, by using a different `printf` format specifier.

Comment: @ThiagoUruray: Using `double` goes not give you a value of 5456.367000 for `5456.367`. “5456.367000” is merely what you get when you print the number rounded to six digits after the decimal point. The actual value, in the format commonly used for `double`, is 5456.367000000000189174897968769073486328125.

Comment: You two are right! `printf("%.20lf\n", number)` => 5456.36700000000018917490